# Avoid WPF Statusbar to increase its height on window vertical resize

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, statusbar

I have a WPF StatusBar and I place it at the bottom by doing the following:

```
<Window>

  <DockPanel>
     <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
         <!-- Grid stuff here -->
     </Grid>

     <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"                   
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

            <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="0">
                <TextBlock Text="Item1"/>
            </StatusBarItem>
            <Separator Grid.Column="1" />
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock />
            </StatusBarItem>
            <Separator Grid.Column="3" />
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="4">
                <TextBlock Text="AnotherItem" />
            </StatusBarItem>
  </DockPanel>

</Window>
```

The problem is when user resizes the window vertically, the Statusbar increases its height and I want to avoid this. I want Statusbar to always keep its height (the same). How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting your VerticalAlignment= Bottom on your status bar. Here is what your new code would be.

```
<DockPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <!-- Grid stuff here -->
        <ListView></ListView>
    </Grid>

    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"                   
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom">

        <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
        <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Item1"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
        <Separator Grid.Column="1" />
        <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2">
            <TextBlock />
        </StatusBarItem>
        <Separator Grid.Column="3" />
        <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="4">
            <TextBlock Text="AnotherItem" />
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
</DockPanel>
```